# JavaScript's setInterval and when the function complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, setinterval

I need to run a function on my node.js server, that completes the same task every 15 minutes.
I Used for that setInterval as in example number 3 here -  http://tinyurl.com/c2jj7dl.
So, I got to something like this:

```
exports.start = function (list, callback){
    setInterval(stuffTop.loadstuff, 900000, list, function (parsedList) {

                // CODE STUFF HERE


                // THEN THE CALLBACK.
        callback(parsedDynamicList);

    });

}
```

**Actually this stuff work, but the function gets completed for the first time - only after 900000MS.
Is there an option to make to function complete (in the first round) - straight when called ? Thanks.**

Comment: Is `stuffTop.loadstuff` synchronous?

Comment: It's another function that accepts a callback, so if I understand correctly the answer is no...

Comment: I'm confused by the four parameters to `setInterval`, that typically takes two.

Comment: So, just take a look at the link I attached...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function which recursivly calls itself:

```
foo = function(){
  doStuff()
  setTimeout(foo,900000)
}
```

In your case It would look like this:

```
exports.start = function (list, callback){
  var foo = function () {
    stuffTop.loadstuff(list, function(parsedList) {
      //CODE STUFF HERE
      //THEN THE CALLBACK
      callback(parsedDynamicList);
      setTimeout(foo,900000);
    });
  }
  foo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your question is simple. Call the function before going into the setInterval. Like this:

```
    var callback=function(){}
    var list=['some','list'];
    var repeaterFunction = function(){console.log("do now!")}

    var start = function (list, callback){
        repeaterFunction();
    var repeater = setInterval(repeaterFunction, 5000, list, function(parsedList){
                    // CODE STUFF HERE
                    // THEN THE CALLBACK.
            callback(parsedDynamicList);

        });

    }   
    start()​
```

The fact that I use `var repeater = setInterval(...` allows for the `clearInterval(repeater)` whenever you wish.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRuB3/)